# Haskell Parse error on 'let'

Tags: haskell, let, rabin-karp

So I'm new to Haskell and I have to program Rabin Karps algorithm.
I feel like my answer should work, but I keep getting a "parse error on 'let'" error when I compile.
Could anybody help me out.

Here is my code:

```
import Data.Char

hash :: String -> Int
hash [] = -1
hash (x:xs) = ((ord x))

rabinKarp :: String -> String -> Bool
rabinKarp [] _ = False
rabinKarp mainString patternString
    let
     hashPattern = hash patternString
     hashMain = hash (take (length pattern) mainString)
    if hashPattern == hashMain
    then True
    else rabinKarp (drop 1 mainString) patternString
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're missing a `=`, and also an `in`

```
rabinKarp mainString patternString =
    let
     hashPattern = hash patternString
     hashMain = hash (take (length pattern) mainString)
    in if hashPattern == hashMain
     then True
     else rabinKarp (drop 1 mainString) patternString
```

EDIT: `in`

Comment: Cheers man, I'm so tired I did an all nighter trying to figure out this assignment and that fixed it.
I would up vote you but I need a rep of 15 or something, thanks so much!